# Is this argument on positive definite matrices correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Let $A$ be a $N\times N$ positive definite matrix. Then, there exists a $N\times 1$ gaussian random vector $a$ such that $A=E[aa^T]$ where $E[.]$ denotes expectation. Then for any given vector $x$, $x^TAx=x^TE[aa^T]x=E[|a^Tx|^2]>0$. Since it is independent of choice of $x$, $x^TAx>0$ for all $x$. What is wrong with the above sort of argument? How will one justify the interchange of expectation and inner product in the equality $x^TE[aa^T]x=E[|a^Tx|^2]$?

Comment: For one, the expectation could be equal to zero.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The expectation cannot be equal to zero since the covariance matrix is positive definite. If it was positive semi definite the expectation could have gone to zero.

Comment: Why not add "probability" to the tags?

Comment: @KarthikUpadhya thanks, missed that detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^T E[aa^T]x=E[|a^Tx|^2] $ since the expectation operator is linear.

We have $$A_{ij} = E[a_i a_j]$$.

$$x^T A x = \sum_i\sum_j x_i x_j A_{ij} = \sum_i\sum_j x_i x_j E[a_i a_j] $$

Now since, $x_i$ and $x_j$ are constants, they can be taken into the expectation. Since the expectation is just an integration, it can be taken out of the summation too.

$$x^T A x = E\left[\sum_i\sum_j x_i x_j a_i a_j\right] = E\left[\left|a^Tx\right|^2\right]  $$

Hope that answered your question.

Comment: To summarize: that argument is indeed correct.

Comment: :) :) @Karthik Happy to see you here!!.

Comment: @dineshdileep The feeling is mutual. I saw that it was you who asked the question after answering it :) You were the one who introduced me to stackexchange by the way :)